# Adding empty string to undefined passes if as true

Tags: javascript, runtime-error, undefined

It drives me crazy and can't see it but as a JavaScript bug:

Every undefined variable added to empty string evaluates to true!(?)

Watch it:

```
var x = {a: 1};

console.log('----y = x[\'b\']----');
var y = x['b']; //can't do x[b]
if(y)
   console.log('f...ed!');
else
   console.log('we are not f...ed!');
console.log('y='+y);
console.log((typeof y)+' (typeof y)');
console.log((y == undefined)+' (y == undefined)');
console.log((y === undefined)+' (y === undefined)');
console.log((y == null)+' (y == null)');
console.log((y === null)+' (y === null)');
console.log('-------------------------');
console.log('----z = x[\'b\']+\'\'----');
var z = x['b']+''; //can't do x[b]
if(z)
   console.log('f...ed!');
else
   console.log('we are not f...ed!');
console.log('z='+z);
console.log((typeof z)+' (typeof z)');
console.log((z == undefined)+' (z == undefined)');
console.log((z === undefined)+' (z === undefined)');
console.log((z == null)+' (z == null)');
console.log((z === null)+' (z === null)');
```

and the results:

```
----y = x['b']----
we are not f...ed!
y=undefined
undefined (typeof y)
true (y == undefined)
true (y === undefined)
true (y == null)
false (y === null)
-------------------------
----z = x['b']+''----
f...ed!
z=undefined
string (typeof z)
false (z == undefined)
false (z === undefined)
false (z == null)
false (z === null)
```

I truly think we are f...ed! (**IE8, FF, Chrome, Opera** agrees with that!)

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/centurianii/6SEqv/

Comment: Is there a question here? This is working as it's supposed to.

Comment: I can't imagine why you'd assume this behavior, which as you point out is *consistent* among implementations, would be a "JavaScript bug". Just because you *think* things should work a certain way doesn't mean they should.

Comment: See p143: http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf

Comment: Also, I don't think anybody is impressed by your barely concealed profanity. If you want people to take your question seriously, leave it out.

Comment: Suppose you were expected a 'logicaly' result of false, this could ruin your code for hours...

Comment: @centurian: `s/you were expected a 'logicaly' result of false/you didn't bother to read any documentation, and instead sat content with your false assumptions/`

Comment: Believe it or not, programming languages operate according to their design, not according to a developer's arbitrary expectations. If you want `undefined` to be evaluated as `false`, then don't convert it to a string. If you convert it to a string, it's a bug in your code, not in JavaScript.,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is as designed, see the spec:

http://ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf

It's not a bug, if it was you probably wouldn't have *every* browser implementing it exactly that way.

Is it goofy? Sure. It's hard to imagine a case where a programmer would actually want `undefined + "foo"` to give `"undefinedfoo"` as an answer. Most other languages would either do nothing, insert an empty string (same as do nothing) or throw an error, but why it works that way in Javascript (or the wisdom of it) is going to be a matter of opinion rather than fact and not an appropriate question for Stack Overflow.

So if your question is "is this a bug?", then the short answer is "no".

Comment: Yes, I've just confirmed it: z === 'undefined' gives true (a string!). I was expecting the empty string(!)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because it's converted to a string:

```
'' + undefined --> "undefined"
```